# Find out when a infinite daily repeating UILocalnotification got fired

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

If a user taps on notification that got fired few days before how to identify the date of firing? I wanted to save the date and status into the app.

Fire date property is giving only the start date for the notification. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, for a repeating local notification you can't know exactly which notification was used to open the app because they're all exact duplicates of each other.

Each time the app is opened you could remove the local notification and create a new one. This would only bound the issue, and you could do the same with a date in user defaults.

You could create explicit notifications instead of repeating if there are enough slots, this is the only way to get close to your requirement with local notifications,

The alternative is push notifications where you can get the server to add additional date info to the push.

Answer (score 1):

Use the property **userInfo** to store the repeating interval (e.g infinite or normal). In the **userInfo** dictionary , store the key "IsInfinite" and value as "Yes/No". By this way you can differentiate the notification type.

**FYI**: check the local notification object information also. Is repeat property is available or not?

Comment: Here my requirement is different. I need to know when it got fired even if the user seeing the notification after few days.

Comment: you can get the fire date from notification dictionary("userInfo") in didReceiveLocalNotification method.

Comment: This fire date will be same as the start date all the time that is the issue here. No use of having a key "IsInfinite"

Answer (score 1):

Since my app works locally so I cannot go for push notifications. Now I am firing notification in a for loop for next 90 days as a possible solution. Its seems like defect with iOS local notifications.

Comment: Not a defect, just not an available feature. It isn't clear how your for loop helps in this case.

Comment: In My case I wanted to capture dates of tapped notifications. So firing separate notifications each day was the only solution i got.